# Visual studio 2010 exiting after program ends

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm trying out Visual studio 2010 by compiling a C program. After it displays the solution in the "DOS" command window, the window is immediately closed. In Visual studio 2008, one gets the message press any key to continue and pressing a key closes the command prompt window. How do I set this behavior in 2010?

Comment: It is no different in VS2010, pressing Ctrl+F5 invokes the "press any key" prompt when the program finishes.

Comment: Yes, I know this shortcut for "start without debugging" but in my case the console window gets dismissed immediately. This is strange.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I found [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540969/missing-press-any-key-to-continue-when-lauching-with-ctrl-f5?wa=wsignin1.0) solution that does not involve modifying your code. It contains a workaround that involves modifying your .vcxproj file.

To do this from within Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (I'm assuming it is similar for Visual Studio 2010), open your project and navigate to the following menu:

```
Project->$YOURPROJECTNAME Properties...
    ->Configuration Properties
        ->Linker
            ->System->SubSystem
```

Then use the dropdown to select **Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)** and apply the change.

"Start without debugging" should do the right thing now.

Comment: Wonderful. This works very fine. And I gave you 1 vote up also. I'm using the Express edition.

Comment: This works great for me thank you. Is there a way to automatically apply this solution to all projects?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is because now in VS 2010 it is possible to create an empty, generic C++ project by default, without having to go through the wizard. This causes VS 2010 to not properly set the `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` flag and so VS2010 has no idea it is a console application for which it would send the usual "Press any key..." prompt.

This problem doesn't occur if you create a Console Application project type from the New Project menu.

But then you can set this flag yourself and many others, through Project/Settings, as the above post has answered correctly!

Answer (score 2):

This is normal.  The "DOS" console window is attached to your program and is supposed to exit when your program finishes.  If you want it to stay open, you need to add code to your program to keep it open.  All you have to do is add a print statement and then input statement to the end of your program.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to stay open, you need to add code to your program. Like it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

... main(...)
{
    your codes
         .
         .
         .

     system("pause");

}
```

if you add this code ,your black screen stay at open. " system("pause") " inside  the stdlib.h header file.

Comment: Your answer would be a bit better if you explained how this was supposed to work. As things stand it's a mysterious incantation and the reader doesn't learn much.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, the "Start Without Debugging" command works in VS2010 exactly the same way it does for me in previous Visual Studio versions (that is, for a console project the console remains open when the process terminates with a "Press any key to continue . . ." prompt).

So, exactly how are you getting VS2010 to run your program?  If you're using the "Ctrl-F5" shortcut, can you verify that Ctrl-F5 is bound to `Debug.StartWithoutDebugging` in "Options/Environment/Keyboard"?

Also, can you try running your program using the menu ("Debug/Start Without Debugging")?

Comment: Thanks. First I compile the file, then build it and then use Debug > start without debugging. I have assigned the "Ctrl-F5" as you told me but I get the same behavior. I admit that it's strange as Visual studio 2005 works fine as expected.

Comment: @yCalleecharan: Interesting - I'm unaware of a setting that controls this.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to believe this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Bring "Start without debug" to the Debug menu...

Tools >> Customize >> Commands(Tab) >> Menu bar(drop down list) >> Debug(Controls Option) >> Add Command(button) >> Debug(Categories List) >> Start without debug

Using "Start without debug" Will allow VS2010 to display the "Press any key to continue" phrase before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application without debugger ("Start without debugging"), the console window will remain open until you press a key.

Comment: hmmm...actually I did that. I know this also applies in Visual studio 2008 and this "command" is what I use to run my programs. So I was a bit surprised of this different behavior in 2010.

Comment: I can confirm that using "start without debugging" in 2010 doesn't keep the console window open after the program exits.

Comment: Yes, with Visual studio 2008 it behaves as expected. I've restarted my machine but I still get the same strange behavior with 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function and call it right before returning from main():

```
void keep_window_open()
{
    // clear buffer
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter a character to exit\n");
    char ch;
    ch = getchar();
    return;
}
```

I adapted it from a C++ version in a utility header file at Bjarne Stroustrup's site:
http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to move the line "char ch" just after the opening brace { after the function definition so as to avoid compilation errors. I think that the line "fflush(stdin)" is C++ code and doesn't work well in C.

Comment: You're right, according to the c FAQ:
http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html
fflush is only defined for output streams.

The link off that FAQ entry discusses how to flush input:
http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: 1 vote up. This piece of code has been a savior. But vitavim (see the post on top) has found a correct solution for this bug and I'm accepting vitavim answer.